# How to add Company logo for all SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to add a company logo for all reports.

Is there an efficient way to do so, or do I have to add the logo for each report manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is SSRS reports, then the slave option, manual change of each report, is the only option. Consider changing only the reports in use.

For MorphX reports you can change the Report Templates for auto design reports. For generated reports you will have change each generated design.

Answer (score 0):

The stock AX Reports have the logo already integrated in the report design, and you can modify the company logo as follows:

Organization administration > Setup > Organization > legal Entities > (select company) > press Company Logo button in the toolbar.

Unfortunately, if you are using customized reports, you will need to add the logo to the datasets and report designs, or as an embedded image in each report design manually.